# Who first put ridges on Ramekins and why?

Tags: cookware

[image: Ramekins]

These white things are called Ramekins. Why do they have the ridges around them and who was the first person to make the ridges on them?

Comment: As a note, not all ramekins are like this. http://bestreviewshub.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/BIA-Cordon-Bleu-Ramekin-Set.jpg for example. Many are also completely smooth.

Comment: Since I have no authoritative source, I'll comment - 1) cosmetic appeal, esp since not all are like that, 2) They are sometimes used for making small pastries, I think a ridged lip would make it easier to press pastry dough into place and have it stay put.

Comment: @AndrewMattson  I agree on the cosmetic appeal, but not on the pastry dough bit, the ramekins OP showed and most I've ever seen are smooth inside. The ridges are on the outside.

Comment: @Stephie - Do you think the ridges might be to make them easier to grip and move (in addition to appearance factors, of course).

Comment: I feel like it's a really old design, like I've seen it in old movies and stuff.

Comment: It's called fluting. Two advantages are that they won't vacuum seal themselves together when stacked and they won't burn as much when handled hot - but I doubt either of these are the reason it was done in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a bit of research I've found a few reasons. One having been mentioned above in a comment, that it removes the risk of the dishes sealing themselves together, or at least reduces.

The most logical, however, is that the flutes create more surface area allowing heat to penetrate much faster, for quick and even cooking.

Comment: So you're saying that in the oven the flutes on the outside, cuz the inside is smooth makes the dish heat up faster?

Answer (score 0):

I saw French, Dutch and possible German sources for the word 'ramekin', which not only refers to the dish, but to some types of baked cheese dishes.
[This is a slightly off-track but interesting article](http://www.theoldfoodie.com/2015/10/what-exactly-is-ramekin.html). Dutch 'rammekens' aren't fluted - so I guess the fluting must have happened in either France or Germany.

In terms of the cookware, various French sites have said that they are used for baking individual dishes then serving them directly at the table, for baine-marie, for egg-based baked dishes and souffles. [In this blog article](http://www.foodrepublic.com/2011/05/12/what-the-heck-is-it-the-ramekin/), although they don't address the reason for the fluted edges, they do say that ramekins have an upright, straight inner edge so that things like souffles can rise properly in them. Also that although they are little they have to be able to withstand very high temperatures - like when blow-torching a creme brulee, without cracking...so these may be clues..?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible that the ridges make it easier to hold them using tongs (for handling while hot).